Elastic Search query upgrade for RangeQuery builder
I am upgrading the elasticsearch version from 8.14.3 to 8.15.3 and there are some issues with this query-
return new RangeQuery.Builder() .field(fieldName) .gte(JsonData.of(dateToday)) .build() ._toQuery;
Here, .field seems to be deprecated. Is there any other way to rewrite the query in the new version?

You need to use as defined below as it is changed in latest version:
new DateRangeQuery.Builder().field("fieldName").gte("dateToday").build()._toRangeQuery();

You can check more into Elastic JavaDoc.

you have to try the RangeQueryBuilders.
import co.elastic.clients.elasticsearch._types.query_dsl.RangeQueryBuilders;

RangeQueryBuilders.term(term -> term.field("fieldName").gte(dateToday))._toQuery();


Since there is a change in the RangeQuery class since version 8.15, you need to use the term method that implies DateRangeQuery, a new class that has the .field that you are looking:
new RangeQuery.Builder().date(_0 -> _0
            .field("fieldName")
            .gte("value")
        ).build()._toQuery();

